# How can I sign my solana transaction which runs with node JS script with existing wallet?

Tags: node.js, web3js, solana

I need to send some SOL from my existing address (created from Phantom wallet) via my node script which was built with solana/web3.js.
I have a private key in my wallet. But I can't sign creating a keypair with my private key string.

```
const from = web3.Keypair.generate();
// how to get my wallet account from private key to from account
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you have the keypair in the form of a byte array, you can use `Keypair.fromSecretKey` to get your keypair: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/82a6bbe06891bc58ed1fa0586ae5d168e68516bd/web3.js/src/keypair.ts#L60

And if you only have the base58 encoded string, you'll have to decode it first, using the bs58 node package:

```
import bs58 from `bs58`;
const decoded = bs58.decode(keypairString);
```

Comment: base58 encoded string means what we can export as private key from a wallet like phantom or sollet

Comment: Getting an error, `Error: Non-base58 character`.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the private key from the wallets, you'll get an array of 8byte integers, something like [244, 13, 5, ...]

You can then convert that into a Keypair using

```
const keyPair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array([244, 13, 5, ...]));
```

You can use the above keyPair to sign

Comment: I have a phantom wallet in which I am not able to report private key in form of a byte array. But @Jon answer works for me. thanks

Comment: What if we only have a string input of the private key? `new Uint8Array(string)` converts each string character to an array element, which is not what we want ‍♂️